# Sphinx Error: Can not import normalize while using command "make html"

Tags: python, python-sphinx, importerror

I was generating documents using sphinx python library, and I encounter the 
`can not import normalize` error.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877382/sphinx-cant-run-make-html) from 2014 but it does not solve my problem.

**Test Code**

```
# hello.py
def myadd(a,b):
    """


        Parameters
    ----------
    a: first parameter
    b: second paramter


    Returns
    -------
    Return: Sum of two arguments

    """
    return a+b

if __name__=="__main__":
     a = myadd(5,6) 
     print('\n')
     print(a)
```

**Sphinx and Locale Installation**

```
import sphinx
from locale import normalize # I got no error here
print(sphinx.__version__) # 1.6.2
```

**Sphinx commands**

```
sphinx-quickstart
> Project name: a
> Author name(s): a
> Create Makefile? (y/n) [y]: 
> Create Windows command file? (y/n) [y]: n
this creates THREE files and THREE folders.
Then,

make html # this gives the error.
```

This procedure works in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ6pFgQXQ0Q).

However, If I repeat the same procedure, I got following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 440, in find
    for nelang in _expand_lang(lang):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 133, in _expand_lang
    from locale import normalize
ImportError: cannot import name normalize
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'html' failed
make: *** [html] Error 1
```

Funny thing is when I import normalize from **locale** I get no error, and
only sphinx gives this error.

**Question**
How can we generate documentation using sphinx by avoiding import error?

Help will be appreciated!!

**Related Links**
http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/tutorial.html
http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/example_google.html

https://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/docstring_python.html
http://gisellezeno.com/tutorials/sphinx-for-python-documentation.html

Comment: Do you have a file or folder called "locale" or "locale.py" somewhere in your project? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10875148/407651

Comment: @mzjn Not really, there is no any locale.py. The project has only one file HELLO.PY

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this. If possible, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn, Me Neither, Now I am testing make html in MAVERICKS, it gives me no problem. But in my MacbookPro Laptop it has Sierra OS, it has inbuilt python2 and I have installed anaconda python3.6. There I got the problem.

Comment: @mzjn, There is no MWE required, "make html" fails for all the python scripts in Sierra OS for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two different installations of Python, namely, python2 and python3.
Both have modules sphinx and somehow they got mixed and gave the problem. For now what I did was following:

```
ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6
ls "/Applications/Python/3.6
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python/3.6
```

Download and install graphical python3 installer from anaconda.
Then it worked without any problems.